# ACCPAC O/E import from EXCEL quote sheet

Tags: vba, excel, odbc, accpac

Have a head cracker here, want to bring the stress levels down and productivity up at work, so here is what I was thinking...

I want to use a Excel quote form and link it to ODBC Pricelist (for item numbers and resent cost) and after the quote is complete, import it in to ACCPAC Invoice Entry...

I am struggling with the import to ACCPAC via VBA (no experience), so if anyone can point me in the right direction to make an export/import template, I can sleep in peace...

working with: ACCPAC 300ERP
            : Microsoft Excel 2010

Comment: Once again Murphy is correct!! I worked on an ACCPAC / Access interface back in 2002, and just last week deleted all my files and code!  However, I did find the following, which should get you started:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472519/accpac-and-excel-spreadsheets

Comment: hahaha, bastard Murphy...
Thanks Wayne, done all the reading there, but unfortunately that's not an option for me, need to import form Excel sheet in to Invoice Entry, slow networks make PSQL access horrible, so running sessions in Excel is a no go...

Comment: Wayne, got a question for you, in my head what I want to do works, however, in your experience, is it possible?..

Comment: Ahh, the power of Google!  I am attaching three links for you to peruse (all three confirm you can import from Excel to ACCPAC). The first mentions generic capabilities   http://www.plus.ca/blog/bid/29941/Accpac-Can-t-Do-That-YES-it-can
The second & third refer to creating a macro in ACCPAC, then tweaking it:
http://sagecity.na.sage.com/support_communities/sage300_erp/f/145/t/69950.aspx?Redirected=true
http://www.pluscommunity.com/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=36259&page=1
-Finally, I assume you can add a reference library for AccPac and expose all methods for Excel VBA?

Comment: What version of Accpac are you using?  You'll want to be importing your quote as an order and in the import template you can indicate that you want to ship quantities and generate an invoice.  However - let's hear more details on what you need to end up with before we start providing detailed answers.

Comment: Morning, Version is 6.1A and you got it just right...
at the moment we quote on an EXCEL sheet and it gets retyped in to ACCPAC, but the ACCPAC system is ridiculously slow so I am hoping to import directly from the quote sheet, hope this is enough info...

Comment: @AlexQue How much programming experience do you have?

Comment: @SilentD, not much but I do have a couple of guys that can help me if I give them something to work with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ways of doing what you're looking for.  The first is to format the data in the Excel sheet to conform to the layout that Sage is looking for when importing an order.  You can populate the quantity shipped fields in the detail lines and put a True value within the field that governs whether Sage should create an invoice when it creates the shipment document.

The Pros to this method is that you don't have to do any programming work.  You can export an existing document into Excel (you can use other layouts but Excel is typically the easiest to work with) and then start to play with the fields that you want to push back into Sage when you do the import.  Once you get the correct layout you very likely can keep that import format even through new versions of order entry.

The Con to this method is that you have to do a lot of fiddling and adjusting and tweeking and correcting and testing.  It will be time consuming.

The other main option is to go with automating Sage through VBA.  Fortunately Sage has the ability to record a macro so that allows you to take your quote information and record the process of adding it into Sage.  That will give you just about all of the code that you'll need to create the quote without using the import engine.

The Pro to this method is that you have 100% control over getting the quote information into Sage.  You are not limited to having the quote information in a specific format (which you do need when importing).  You're also able to perform any validations that you want to perform and update the Excel workbook with information that Sage generates (like the order, shipment and invoice document numbers).

The Con to this method is that you're responsible for much of the coding.  The macro will give you most of the code but you need to clean it up, put relevant code into loops, check for errors, etc.

That's why I asked if you have programming experience.  If not then I don't recommend the VBA route because you'll have to be learning how to program using VBA at the same time as you're learning how to get transactions in to Sage.  The Import/Export engine is powerful but somewhat inflexible.

Other options:
Contact your Sage dealer.  They will either have someone on staff who can do this sort of work or they can get in contact with a sub-contractor to do this for you.

http://www.realisable.co.uk/
Realisable's IMAN is a piece of software that is designed to assist you with the transformation of source data to get it into Sage (and other systems).  It is possible to configure IMAN to read your Excel workbook and turn that into an order/shipment/invoice in Sage - with very little coding if any at all.

Comment: Morning, this is perfect @SilentD, i recon the first method is the way to go for us and with this info I can get my guys on the right track :D...
Unless the company buy an integration package, will offer it to them...
unfortunately the Accpac support stuff are not very clued up in this around here, but hey, this give me hope so I'll consider this as solved...
Sidebar: Ill try to post the results here if we manage to pull this of...